# How to check the integrity of Live USB in Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu from a live USB but always encounter errors in the copying files installation phase.

The error message says that this I/O error are commonly due to faulty Medium or HDD. I'm checking my SSD and making a new Live USB to try again.

So this is my concern I can md5sum the ISO I download, but how do I check the live USB is good?

Comment: I would suspect that other hardware is throwing the error , such as motherboard. I've used same USB that I was using for 3 other installations for an old PC , as well as live CD, but in no way it was successfull. I had to use another computer with SATA to USB controller to install Ubuntu there and then plug in the HDD back to the computer.

Comment: I don't get it @Serg . His question is asking about how does he check the live USB is good? right

Comment: probably not enough ram, try this instead https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: @BeGood If you've read the question, you can see that OP mentioned I/O error while trying to install from a live USB. Live USB itself may be totally fine, but there may be issue with other hardware.

Comment: Voted to reopen because this question is not a duplicate of the linked question: they're asking how to check *if* the Live USB has defects, not how to check *which* defect(s) it has (which would imply by premise that the Live USB *is* defective, which is something yet to be determined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the integrity of the image written to the USB drive by checking its MD5 sum against the original ISO's MD5 sum:

1. Check the original ISO's size:

   ```
   % ls -l archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso 
   -rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 689963008 nov 22 21:35 archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso
   ```
2. Run this command (replace `/dev/sdc` with the actual device and change `689963008` according to the original ISO's size):

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/sdc iflag=fullblock count=$((689963008/512)) 2>/dev/null | md5sum -
   ```
3. Check the output against the original ISO's MD5 sum.

If you want to get fancy:

1. Enable the Universe repository (you can do that in Software & Updates);
2. Install `pv`: `sudo apt-get install pv`;
3. Check the original ISO's size:

   ```
   % ls -l archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso 
   -rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 689963008 nov 22 21:35 archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso
   ```
4. Run this command (replace `/dev/sdc` with the actual device and change `689963008` according to the original ISO's size):

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/sdc iflag=fullblock count=$((689963008/512)) 2>/dev/null | pv -s 689963008 | md5sum -
   ```
5. Check the output against the original ISO's MD5 sum.

Comment: Please explain the downvote. This method works perfectly, so I guess the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Does it work with LiveUSB ?. I mean after make a boots file in USB, whole file are extracted from iso.

Comment: @BeGood Not sure what you mean exactly, but this will work either if done from an installed system or from a Live USB, even if the running system has been booted from the Live USB itself.

Comment: So it likes `Check disk  for defects` right?

Comment: The package is not available in the 15.10 repos. So cannot try out.

sudo apt-get install pv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pv

Comment: @BeGood No, the option you're referring to checks if the disk is physically damaged, this method is useful only to check if the image written to the drive corresponds to the original non-broken image (which on the other hand on success implies that the drive is not damaged in correspondence of any of the read blocks).

Comment: @user3005629 Yes, I didn't mention that you'll have to enable the Universe repository in order to install `pv` (you can do that in Software & Updates).

Comment: As mention in Q he said :  So this is my concern I can md5sum the ISO I download, but how do I check the live USB is good ? . and the source said “Check disk for defects” will compare the checksums of the files on the USB drive against a known good list.

Comment: @BeGood My bad, I thought that option would have run a S.M.A.R.T. test or something. Then yes it's basically the same, but you don't necessarily need to boot the Live USB.

Comment: if the same you should give a question and a solution is how to check disk for defects liveUSB without boots itself. I'm sure that will be my favvorite question

Comment: @BeGood I'm not sure what you mean. The question is "How to check the integrity of Live USB in Ubuntu 15.10 amd 64 ( Not Xubuntu )"; this answer seems to fit it.

Comment: I down-voted it because it was not applicable in my condition. But that's not really part of the question. My condition was that I was on a Live session but once by luck i could finally install Ubuntu after trying for TWO days then I finally can try your method and approve it. 

The software sources are enabled by default so no need to add them.

I will try out and check your answer as approved.

Comment: @user3005629 1. This works from the Live session. 2. Even if it wouldn't have worked from the Live session, please explain how are people supposed to know about your condition if you don't point that out in the question.

Comment: As you can observe my first reply was about getting pv installed because I was confused by the alternative and thought I also needed it for the main answer.  So it looked incomplete but now I re-read the answer and after your reply on the comments found you weren't suggesting a software that was not in the repos. My bad.

Note: See that I included the Ubuntu version

Comment: Kos would you please add the documentation here and quote a reference to the part that shows the method with dd ?  Since your answer has been pointed as an exact duplicate. But the other answer doesn't emphasize this way of checking the USB.

Comment: @kos read the previous comment

Comment: @user3005629 I'm not sure what do you want me to do exactly, add a reference to what? However on the duplicate part, I voted to reopen your question, since the questions are not duplicates at all IMO.

Comment: I agree and sorry I let loose ends before asking for the reference I meant this part: 

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#Check_the_CD

I only speculate that maybe this is the part that made them think this is a duplicate. But you could reference your answer there and say is the same method stated there but for a USB Live image. Good day! :D

Comment: So... is the first method sufficient or not? Is the second one more reliable, or does it just give more information? I.e., what's the difference?