# Error while burning CD-R, check if it's burned correctly

Tags: burning

I tried to write an .iso file on a CD-R, but I got an error in process.

```
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 5Ch READ BUFFER CAPACITY: See MMC specs: Sense Key 3 "Medium error", ASC 10 ASCQ 00
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): [5 64 00] Illegal mode for this track
BraseroLibburn Closing
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Libburn reported an error SCSI error on write(1136,16): [5 64 00] Illegal mode for this track
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 1
    message = "SCSI error on write(1136,16): [5 64 00] Illegal mode for this track"
BraseroLibburn stopping
Session error : SCSI error on write(1136,16): [5 64 00] Illegal mode for this track (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)
```

When I opened the resulted disk, most files are ended up written there, but I'm not sure if that's all of them. When I tried to boot from this disk, nothing happened. How to check if this .iso was burned correctly?

Comment: You can use `md5sum` to compare the written files to the original files.  If the sums don't match, that means that file failed.

Comment: @Terrance there is this weird area on the .iso, which is marked as [BOOT] if I look inside iso with File Roller. I don't know how to even look at this in the actual CD, it's invisible here. I don't know how to compare those two. I guess the placement of it on CD is also important, and I don't know how to look at it.

Comment: Look at @kos answer just written.  It is exactly how to check them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a duplicate, so I'll readapt an old answer of mine.

---

You can check the integrity of the image written to the CD by checking its MD5 sum against the original ISO's MD5 sum:

1. Check the original ISO's size:

   ```
   % ls -l archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso 
   -rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 689963008 nov 22 21:35 archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso
   ```
2. Run this command (change `689963008` according to the original ISO's size):

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/cdrom iflag=fullblock count=$((689963008/512)) 2>/dev/null | md5sum -
   ```
3. Check the output against the original ISO's MD5 sum:

   ```
   % md5sum archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso
   b6781474851992cd9deb03b93a3f9503  archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso
   ```

If you want to get fancy:

1. Enable the Universe repository (you can do that in Software & Updates);
2. Install `pv`: `sudo apt-get install pv`;
3. Check the original ISO's size:

   ```
   % ls -l archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso 
   -rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 689963008 nov 22 21:35 archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso
   ```
4. Run this command (change `689963008` according to the original ISO's size):

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/cdrom iflag=fullblock count=$((689963008/512)) 2>/dev/null | pv -s 689963008 | md5sum -
   ```
5. Check the output against the original ISO's MD5 sum:

   ```
   % md5sum archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso
   b6781474851992cd9deb03b93a3f9503  archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso
   ```

Comment: You beat me to the answer, but exactly what I believe the asker needs.  +1  =)

Comment: @Terrance It also feels a bit uncomfortable because this is almost a copy-paste of this one... http://askubuntu.com/a/701257/380067. The problem is it doesn't really seem right to close this question as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I can definitely agree with you there.  =)

Comment: @PeretFinctor you could mount the iso file, then compare the cd to the iso.  The command would be `diff --brief -r dir1 dir2`.

Comment: Please ignore that thing about binary diff, this program screwed up right at the start, all the files actually were empty. I haven't tried to actually look inside any of them, they showed a correct sizes in the file manager.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're using an empty CD-R. This can only be written once, and after that it's only readable...

Which means; since the `.iso` hasn't burnt onto the CD-R correctly, you can't do anything about it.

Throw it away, and maybe try using a CD-RW?

Comment: Yes, that's the main issue here. I need to know if everything was written correctly, or if all hope is lost and I can throw this CD-R out now.

Comment: @PeretFinctor ahhh - so this CD-R had nothing on it previously?

Comment: @PeretFinctor edit to answer

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to get a md5sum of a cd disk. Hm, maybe I can get iso back from the disk, and then compare those two iso files for equality. But I'm not sure if they work like that...

Answer (score 1):

i am the developer of libburn.

The burn run was a clear failure. Possibly because the CD was
already written and closed. There were at most 1136 * 2048
bytes written (~ 2 MB). So everything else which you can read
from the CD must stem from a previous burn run.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas