# Corrupt pendrive after making live Ubuntu installer

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb, gparted, dd

I have sandisk 8GB

I had kali linux installed. I tried to create Bootable live Ubuntu pendrive. I went to the terminal and issued the following commands:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1k count=2048

sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel msdos

sudo parted -a none /dev/sdb mkpart  primary fat32 0 2048

mkfs.vfat -n "Disk" /dev/sdb1

sudo dd if=./ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdd bs=8129
```

It created bootable live USB installer for Ubuntu successfully.

After dual booting my latop with Ubuntu and Kali linux I now need the pendrive for data storing purpose

It was showing a capacity of only 64 MB. I used `dd` command to reformat it but that wouldn't help. I also used `gparted` but that didn't help.

What to do now?

Comment: since its a pen drive .. did you go into gparted and just delete all the partitions then create a new one with the file system you are looking for ... most likely you are only viewing a small partition on the drive and there is other partitions or unpartitioned space on the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem. It's quite easy once you gain the basic understanding. The main thing is that in Linux you should never use graphical user interface and always stick with terminal. I did the following in terminal:

```
sudo su
```

This makes me sudo user by default without the need to put sudo at first everytime

```
fdisk -l
```

This checks for the present disks. Thus I can safely determine my pendrive to be sdb. dd is destructive command and has to be carefully used against correct drive

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

This overwrites the entire disk with zeros. It wipes all present file systems and partition tables. The disk at this point is useless.

```
parted /dev/sdb
```

This starts the parted program which is a powerful CLI program to create partition tables

```
mklabel gpt
```

This creates gpt partition table for the disk

```
quit
```

This quits parted program

```
mpunt -a
```

After altering or creating a new partition table /etc/fstab has to be reloaded. This can be done by rebooting the computer. However this one line terminal command also does the same job

```
umount /dev/sdb
```

Now in order to create partitions of different file systems /dev/sdb has to be unmounted first

```
mkfs -t ext4 -L SANDISK /dev/sdb
```

This creates file partition of type ext4. Here -t argument is for file type. -L argument is for the label of the disk. Here the disk is named 'SANDISK'

That's it

Comment: And then check this out XD - http://askubuntu.com/questions/701249/how-to-check-the-integrity-of-live-usb-in-ubuntu-15-10-amd-64-not-xubuntu

Comment: That's great, glad you finally solved it, and I learned something too :-)

Comment: A similar answer  is given by @Zanna to a similar question at the following link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/781223/physical-block-size-is-2048-bytes-but-linux-says-it-is-512-when-formatting-a

Answer (score 5):

You can try to select "Create partition table", under the device menu in Gparted, in order to fully reformat it. (Select msdos as the partition table type). Then, you should be able to create a new partition on the USB stick.

---

If that doesn't work, a very simple (But slow, and I'm sure there's a better way) way to fix this would be to simply overwrite the *entire* drive with `dd`, by using something like this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

Which will overwrite the entire contents with zeroes, after which you should be able to create a partition table and a partition with Gparted as described above.

Comment: I followed your instructions but problem is half solved

Comment: @rancho What do you mean by "half solved" - what isn't working ?

Comment: After executing the dd command in terminal gparted correctly determined the size to be 8 GB. I went to Devicce --> Create partition table -->gpt --> Apply. I got the error that the task was successfully carried out but system was unable to inform the kernel. I right clicked on unallocated spaces and issued command to create fat32 partition using the entire space. It gave a pop up window saying an error occurred while applying the operation. What to do now?

Comment: @rancho Close gparted, Unplug USB stick and plug it in again, and then try creating the partition with gparted again.

Comment: @JonazCz Can you please follow my conversation with Bharadwaj Raju. It would be of great help to me?

Answer (score 2):

Try `mkfs.vfat`.

Assuming your pendrive is `/dev/sdb`

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -I -n "Name you want" /dev/sdb
```

will create a new FAT32 filesystem on `/dev/sdb`. (If you want NTFS, replace `mkfs.vfat` with `mkfs.ntfs`)

Explanation of `-I`:

`-I` creates a filesystem on the entire `/dev/sdb` device, removing any previous partitions.

From `man mkfs.vfat`:

```
-I  It is typical for fixed disk devices to be partitioned so, by default, you are not permitted to create a filesystem across the entire device.  mkfs.fat  will  complain  and  tell  you  that  it  refuses  to  work.  This is different when using MO disks.  One doesn't always need partitions on MO disks.  The filesystem can go 
    directly to the whole disk.  Under other OSes this is known as the 'superfloppy' format.  This switch will force mkfs.fat to work properly.
```

Comment: I followed your instructions. But still the problem is not solved completely. Now when viewed in the result in gparted, there is a red exclamation mark on the immediate right of /dev/sdb. Is it something to be worried about?

Comment: Most probably no.

Comment: In gparted the option to delete the partition is greyed out. I can do this operation in other pen drives. Also I am unable to resize the partition so as to create two partitions. Something is surely wrong.

Comment: @rancho - try closing gparted, unplugging the USB drive, and then try again. Perhaps also reboot if that doesn't work ?

Comment: @JonasCz I did everything but in gparted the red exclamation mark immediately to the right of /dev/sdb is still present. And as usual the options to delete and resize the partition are not working.

Comment: @rancho, you should be able to right-click on it an select "information", alternatively "View" > "device information" in the main menu, does it tell you anything relevant ?

Comment: @JonasCz Yes it is giving me this warning: plain floppy: device "dev/sdb" busy (Resource temporarily unavailable): Cannot initialize '::' mlabel: Cannot initialize drive. However I did reboot the PC and currently the pendrive is unmounted

Comment: @rancho, You could try this: [How to format a USB drive?](http://askubuntu.com/q/198065) Otherwise I don't know what could be wrong, but you could try in windows ? Perhaps your USB stick died and is broken ? I've had that happen too.

Comment: @JonasCz Windows is not displaying any error and in Windows it is working perfectly normal as a 8 GB pendrive. In linux too it is working normal as 8 GB pen drive for data storage. However problem comes only in gparted when I try to delete or resize partition.

Comment: @rancho In that case, I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: @rancho: The `-I` switch to `mkfs.vfat` creates filesystems *without a partition*.  That is, the filesystem takes up the whole disk, with no room left over for the partition table or other such metadata.  I imagine that is why you are unable to resize partitions: There is no partition to resize.

Comment: Any way out of this?

Comment: @Kevin Thanks you made the problem clear to me and helped me solve it